# HP ProCurve 2520G Switch not accepting HP transceiver SFP

Tags: hp, hp-procurve, sfp, power-over-ethernet

I first tried a non HP optical transceiver, received the error:

```
Not an HP Networking transceiver
```

Called HP they said I need to order a HP branded optical transceiver part no 468508-002  so I did. $200 dollars later.

I inserted into the switch and got the same error, even tried power cycling. 
thank you .

Running the latest firmware.

Tried the following commands as well:

```
HP-2520G-8-PoE> allow-unsupported-transceiver
Invalid input: allow-unsupported-transceiver
HP-2520G-8-PoE> config
Invalid input: config
HP-2520G-8-PoE> enable
Username: manager
Password:
HP-2520G-8-PoE# allow-unsupported-transceiver
Invalid input: allow-unsupported-transceiver
HP-2520G-8-PoE# config
HP-2520G-8-PoE(config)# allow-unsupported-transceiver
Invalid input: allow-unsupported-transceiver
HP-2520G-8-PoE(config)# enable
Invalid input: enable
HP-2520G-8-PoE(config)# exit
HP-2520G-8-PoE# allow-unsupported-transceiver
Invalid input: allow-unsupported-transceiver
HP-2520G-8-PoE# enable
Invalid input: enable
HP-2520G-8-PoE# config
HP-2520G-8-PoE(config)# allow-unsupported-transceiver
Invalid input: allow-unsupported-transceiver
HP-2520G-8-PoE(config)#
ROM information:
   Build directory: /sw/rom/build/wallerom(t4b)
   Build date:      Oct 26 2009
   Build time:      14:31:18
   Build version:   J.14.05
   Build number:    28079
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The 468508-002 is a short-wave (850 nm) 8Gb SFP+ transceiver for Fibre Channel. It is not compatible with Ethernet switches and won't ever work in a 2520.

Provision switches like the 2520 series accept their own family of transceivers, e.g. J4858C (1000BASE-SX), J4859C (1000BASE-LX), J8177C (1000BASE-T). Check the [transceiver compatibility guide](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c05115518) and the [2520 Quickspecs](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/default.aspx?cc=us&lc=en&oid=4063682).

You can check the transceiver status by running `show tech transceiver` (more recent switches support `show interfaces transceiver detail`). If it doesn't show up you can check the log `log -r`.

As far as I can see, `allow-unsupported-transceiver` was added to the (Aruba-branded) 2530 series but not the 2520. Anyway, an SFP+ module won't likely work in an SFP port.

You can get 3rd-party, compatible SFP transceivers for as low as $10.

Comment: In addition, it will help a lot if the 3rd party SFP is preprogrammed for HP/Cisco/Juniper etc.

Comment: @cown Absolutely - saves you the hassle to `allow-unsupported-transceiver`.

Comment: thanks will  J4858C-AX  work? i can not find that data in the PDFs...

Comment: @user3265051 If it's "HP J4858C compatible" it'll work. It's for 1000BASE-SX (over up to 550m of multi-mode fiber).